# Modx api как удалить файл из директории?

Tags: api, modx

В **modx api** есть возможность удалить ресурс, объект. Я делаю страницу "изменить фотографии профиля". Пытаюсь сделать следующее - когда юзер загрузил новые фотографии и нажал кнопку сохранить, то надо бы удалить старые фотографии из папки в корне **public_html/user_upload**. Я получаю ссылки на старые фотографии. С помощью какой команды можно выполнить удаление файлов?

Пробовал на обум вот так, но не вышло.

```
$modx->remove($photo1);
```

Или modx api это делать не умеет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modx api так **не умеет**. Пришлось решать вопрос через `php unlink();`